# ImportError pyramid hello world program

Tags: pyramid

source code:

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
from pyramid.config import Configurator
from pyramid.response import Response

def hello_world(request):
    return Response('<h1>Hello world!</h1>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config = Configurator()
    config.add_view(hello_world)
    app = config.make_wsgi_app()
    server = make_server('0.0.0.0', 8080, app)
    server.serve_forever()
```

When I ran the sample hello_world program using pyramid, I got the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "application.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pyramid.config import Configurator
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/config/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pyramid.interfaces import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyramid/interfaces.py", line 3, in <module>
    from zope.interface import (
ImportError: No module named interface
```

Comment: Please show us the source code..

Comment: @intelis added source code

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was a misconfiguration on the part of the user.

Answer (score 0):

You've installed something improperly - more than likely by using `python setup.py develop` somewhere instead of using `pip install -e .`. If you mix tools you're going to have some issues. This particular one seems to be due to namespace packages not being configured correctly which almost always is a symptom of using easy_install and pip in the same environment. You need to pick one (preferably pip), and sometimes the decision about which one to use was already made by whatever tool installed python for you.